# Listing Folders AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to ng-repeat some kind of folders, here is my code : HTML:

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="miControlador">





      <li class="left-menu-list-submenu">
                <a class="left-menu-link" href="javascript: void(0);" ng-click="vm.getfolders();">
                    <i class="left-menu-link-icon fa fa-folder"></i>
                    Catalogs
                </a>
                <ul class="left-menu-list list-unstyled" style="margin-left:20px;" ng-repeat="fol in folders">
                    <li>
                        <a style="cursor:pointer;" ng-click="vm.more_folders();">{{fol}}</a>
                        <br />
                        <a style="cursor:default;color:black;" ng-repeat="more in more_folders">
                        <ul>
                          <li>{{more}}</li>
                        </ul>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>


  </div>
```

Js:

```
  var vm = this;

    vm.getfolders = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'GET' ,
            url: 'link_folders.json',
        })
            .then(function successCallback(data) {
                console.log("folders");
                $scope.folders = data.data;

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });
    };
    vm.getfolders();

    vm.more_folders = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'GET' ,
            url: 'more_folders.json',
        })
            .then(function successCallback(data) {
                console.log("more_folders");
                $scope.more_folders = data.data;

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });
    };

    vm.more_folders();
```

link_folders.json:

```
[
    "/visualizer/360", 
    "/visualizer/2D"
]
```

more_folders.json:

```
[
    "/visualizer/360/Eva", 
    "/visualizer/2D/Ferb", 
    "/visualizer/360/Andy", 
    "/visualizer/2D/John"
]
```

Here is my plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/SW7fqSajpYtQCJdY6wZb?p=preview

What i want - ng-repeat only this objects, which string is like above catalog, something like that -

```
/visualizer/2D

/visualizer/2D/Ferb
/visualizer/2D/John
```

Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: @Hey24sheep I want something like i show this after "something like that - ", ex. only show "/visualizer/2D/ferb" under "/visualizer/2D"

Comment: now in plunker i show exactly what i want : https://plnkr.co/edit/upylYHTiaeJbXkfT8SWO?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I got you. I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What i want - ng-repeat only this objects, which string is like above
>   catalog, something like that -
>
> /visualizer/2D
>
> /visualizer/2D/Ferb /visualizer/2D/John

To get data filtered like that, All you need is a filter on your second ng-repeat

```
ng-repeat="more in more_folders | filter:  fol ">
```

This will filter and then print the result which match your fol data.

To read more about filter, refer to [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)